# Published Blazor Wasm - DLL on subpath gives 404 NotFound

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly

I have a blazor wasm application running on a subpath **Apps/Genesis/**
The problem is some DLL's are not being found:

The request is:

https://localhost:5001/Apps/Genesis/Apps/Genesis/_framework/Blazored.LocalStorage.dll

The request should be:

https://localhost:5001/Apps/Genesis/_framework/Blazored.LocalStorage.dll

```
app.MapWhen(
    context =>
    {
        return context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Apps/Genesis");
    },
    genesis =>
    {
        // Define blazor files
        genesis.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/Apps/Genesis");

        // Access static files (Ex.: images, dll's) - Used twice because it's on the microsoft docs example
        genesis.UseStaticFiles();
        genesis.UseStaticFiles("/Apps/Genesis");

        // Apply routing for UseEndpoints
        genesis.UseRouting();

        // Especify Routes
        genesis.UseEndpoints(
            endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("Apps/Genesis/{{*path:nonfile}}", "Apps/Genesis/index.html");
            });
    });
```

Comment: I don't know Blazor, but is it trying to reference the file by URL then? Can you show us the request please and the exact error please? Also note the capital E in your JSON: is it capital E on disk? Is Blazor's web server case sensitive? (i.e. it does the routing in memory not on disk here)

Comment: I have edited the question, the capital E was a mistype. The request is
https://localhost:5001/Apps/Genesis/_framework/Example.dll. Should be
https://localhost:5001/Apps/Genesis/_framework//x86/Example.dll

Comment: WASM is web assembly. It has no bitness, just as Javascript has no bitness. It's neither x86 nor x64. Why does that assembly require architecture-specific files?

Comment: I have rephrased the question.